# Query getting names with count of at least 1 in Switzerland

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

any ideas on how to resolve this?

In the query below i want to bring in the results all the names that have that have a count of at least 1 in Switzerland in the combination.

I've tried creating a temp table as per further down that I think it works but there must be a easiest way to resolve:

```
SELECT c.name, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'Germany' THEN 1 END) as 'Germany', 
COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'London' THEN 1 END) as 'London',     
COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'Switzerland' THEN 1 END) as 'Switzerland',   
COUNT(CASE WHEN country NOT IN('London', 'Ireland') THEN 1 END) as 'others' 
FROM a_products p 
JOIN a_customers c 
on id_customer = c.id 
Group By name
```

Potential solution:

```
select *
into #Swiss
from a_products
where country = 'Switzerland' 

SELECT c.name, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'Germany' THEN 1 END) as 'Germany', 
COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'London' THEN 1 END) as 'London',     
COUNT(CASE WHEN country = 'Switzerland' THEN 1 END) as 'Switzerland',   
COUNT(CASE WHEN country NOT IN('London', 'Ireland') THEN 1 END) as 'others' 
FROM a_products p 
JOIN a_customers c 
on p.id_customer = c.id 
JOIN #Swiss s
on p.id_customer = s.id_customer
where s.id_customer is not null
Group By name
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and output. It will be easy to check. :-)

Answer (score 1):

count is for not null values  and you case when country = '...'   is always != from null in these case you could try using SUM and manage checked  value as 1 and not checked  as 0

```
SELECT c.name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'Germany' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as Germany, 
SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'London' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as London,     
SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'Switzerland' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as Switzerland,   
SUM(CASE WHEN country NOT IN('London', 'Ireland') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as others
FROM a_products p 
JOIN a_customers c 
on id_customer = c.id 
Group By name
```

and for flilter the value for Switzerland you can use having

```
SELECT c.name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'Germany' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as Germany, 
SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'London' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as London,     
SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'Switzerland' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as Switzerland,   
SUM(CASE WHEN country NOT IN('London', 'Ireland') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as others
FROM a_products p 
JOIN a_customers c 
on id_customer = c.id 
Group By name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'Switzerland' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) >=1
```

or simply

```
SELECT c.name,  
SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'Switzerland' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as Switzerland 
FROM a_products p 
JOIN a_customers c 
on id_customer = c.id 
Group By name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'Switzerland' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) >=1
```

Comment: i just replaced HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'Switzerland' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) >1 with HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN country = 'Switzerland' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) >=1 and it's given me exactly what i needed..  :)

Comment: @AlexSanchez  ..correct answer  updated with >=